# Using multipart/form-data header to upload files using vuejs, laravel, axios causes 401

Tags: laravel, axios

I am trying to upload file using axios library.

```
axios.post('/images/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }).then( response => console.log(response))
```

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')
 ->group( function() {
  Route::post('/images/upload', 'ImageController@store');
})
```

I get the following error with status code

```
{"message": "unauthenticated"}
```

The moment I remove the header part i.e. "multipart/form-data", the request goes through, but that's no bueno since I need to send the file as well.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport or Token Authentication?

Comment: No, I am not using passport, just CSRF token.

Comment: You're using token authentication (CSRF is for a different thing), did you create access tokens for users?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using token authentication and it works for all other requests, just not when the multipart/form-data header is present.

Comment: I have created access tokens for users and I checked - they are sent with the request.

Comment: make sure `formData` getting the requested file or not.

Comment: `FormData.has('image')` in my case returns `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem when trying to reproduce this

Send a Bearer header with the api_token in the header

for example

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div id="app">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="upload()">
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script>
    function upload() {
        let image = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', image);
        axios.post('/images/upload', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer {{ auth()->user()->api_token }}',
            }
        }).then( response => console.log(response))
    }
</script>
```

Assuming a controller function like this

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('public');
    return $path;
}
```

You would get the stored image url in the response

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Life saver! Do you have any idea why do I need to do it like that?

Comment: Because the `auth:api` middleware checks for an `api_token` in the `Authorization` header of requests

Comment: Ok, but it only seems to happen when the "multipart/form-data"  header is added, how does that affect it?

Comment: Should not affect it, you'd need an Authorization header whether you're posting an image or just text

Comment: Yes, that is the thing, I use an axios interception to add the api_token on each post request, however, the moment I add this header, it is no longer included.

Comment: included* maybe the interceptor is only catching axios calls for text data